# Magento 302 custom rest api

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have enabled ssl in my nginx configuration and also enabled https for frontend in magento. When I am trying to hit a custom module controller action from my android device, It's automatically redirected to 302. I am hitting this url "http://www.exampleur.com/data/response" with post datas in body from andorid device. But I am getting this response in access log

`146.50.59.80 - - [01/Jan/2017:01:20:27 -0500] "POST /data/response/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"`

Post datas are going as empty to the secure url. I don't like to hit the secure url directly. Is there any way to pass the post datas to secure url when there is 302 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

IN all over the web 301 stands for permanent redirect, and 302 stands for temporary redirect

So when you hit [this](http://www.exampleur.com/data/response) Url It wont contain https But your magento site has https for frontend.

so magento redirect you to https domain so you get 302 redirect message try with this https://www.exampleur.com/data/response url contain https with it

Comment: Is there any way to pass the post values to https when there is a 302 redirect